# Installing RTree and geopandas in windows 10 64 bit OS

Tags: python, geopandas

I tried installing geopandas in python 3.6 with no error but when I import the module in python I got this error.

could not find or load spatialindex_c.dll

The same thing happens to RTree, displaying also the same error, but has installed correctly using the following commands:

For geopandas:

pip install geopandas-0.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl

For RTree:

pip install Rtree-0.8.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

What could be the problems with these?

The following libraries have already been installed and are working: gdal, fiona, scipy, missingno, shapely, pysal, numpy, pandas and matplotlib.

Comment: The problem is that the windows installer from PyPI does not contains `libspatialindex` (a C dependency). The wheels you can download from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rtree do contain them, so that can be a solution (however, another solution would be to use the Anaconda distribution, which has all those packages pre-compiled as well)